# how to add jfxrt.jar in openjdk8

Tags: java, javafx

I am using OpenJDK 8 and want to add jfxrt.jar in my MS project. I am getting NoClassDefFoundError for FXCollection.class. My MS project is deployed on a Kubernetes pod. Is there any way to add jfxrt.jar there and to resolve given error.

I tried to add a `COPY` command in the Docker file, but it is giving error like file not found.

I didn't got any compatible dependency version of it from Maven Central.

Comment: Please provide some code which makes it easier to answer your question

Answer (score 0):

JDK8 and JavaFX are obsolete. You can find info on modern JDK and JavaFX distributions (currently 21), at [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/). BellSoft and Azul also provide JDKs that include JavaFX.

BellSoft offer [JDK 8 distributions](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/) (select "JDK 8 LTS" + "Full JDK") that include JavaFX, you could try one of those if you wish. The JavaFX Media and Webkit components in BellSoft Liberica JDK 8 do not work.

Regarding jfxrt.jar. It does not exist in recent versions of JavaFX. It also does not exist in most OpenJDK distributions. It does exist in archived Oracle JDK 8 versions. You can't just copy the jfxrt.jar that you may find somewhere into an Open JDK distribution and expect it to work. JavaFX requires native components matching the Java runtime versions in order for it to work and those native components (e.g. DLLs or .so libraries) are not included in jfxrt.jar.

JavaFX also may not function within a kubernetes pod as you are trying to run it.